# How to print the corresponding ID to the max() value

Tags: r, max

From a data frame I have to calculate which person (Customer column) has been spending the most.
I have made a cumulative sum (`csum` column) of each persons spending, but when I print the maximum value I also want the person's name to show.

```r
max(mydata$csum, na.rm = TRUE) --> prints only the max value
```

I want something that prints both the max value and the customer's name.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `which.max` to get the index, use that to subset the column or columns of interest

```
i1 <- which.max(mydata$csum)
mydata$Customer[i1]
mydata[i1, c("Customer", "csum")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Customer =c("a","b","c"),csum=c(1,5,2))
setDT(df1)[csum==max(csum),.(Customer,csum)]
```